# Solving $A_n A_{n+1}=A_{n}+2 A_{n+1}$ to disagree with a question

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solving $$A_n A_{n+1}=A_{n}+2 A_{n+1} \tag1$$ to disagree with a question attached below:

[image]

Let us re-write *1) as
$$A_{n+1}(A_n-2)=A_n \tag 2$$
Let $A_n-2=B_n/B_{n-1}$ in (2) to simplify and to  get
$$B_{n+1}-2B_{n-1}+B_n=0 \tag3$$
Let $B_n=x^n$, we get $x^2+x-2=0 \implies x=1,-2.$
We get $$B_n=P +Q (-2)^n \tag4$$. Finally we get
$$A_n=\frac{P+Q(-2)^n}{P+Q(-2)^{n-1}}+2=\frac{3P}{P+Q(-2)^{n-1}}\tag5$$
The solution of (1) given by (5) is algebraic of exponential but not not periodic.

Can one justify the attached question containing the recurrence relation (1)?

**Edit:**
Let $Q/P=R$, to write $$A_n=\frac{3}{1+R(-2)^{n-1}}.$$

Comment: If you set $Q = 0$, then $a_n$ will be "periodic" with $a_n = 3$ for all $n$. This could also be realized by setting $a_n = a_{n+1}$ in the recurrence.

Comment: Also, the final solution for $A_n$ can be reduced to two variables by dividing the numerator and denominator by $P$ and setting $t = Q/P$. It would become $\frac{3}{1 + t(-2)^{n-1}}$.

Comment: We could also rewrite the recurrence as
$$
(A_n - 2)(A_{n+1} - 1) = 2
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a Ricatti recurrence:

$\begin{align*}
   w_{n + 1}
      = \frac{a w_n + b}{c w_n + d}
\end{align*}$

with $c \ne 0$ and $a d - b c \ne 0$. There are several ways to solve them. Brand "A Sequence Defined by a Recurrence Relation", AMM 62:7 (1955), pp 489-492 goes as follows.

Define:

$\begin{align*}
  y_{n + 1}
    &= \alpha - \frac{\beta}{y_n} \\
  \alpha
    &= a + d \\
  \beta
    &= a d - bc
\end{align*}$

Replacing $y_n = x_{n + 1} / x_n$ gives now:

$\begin{align*}
   x_{n + 2} - \alpha x_{n + 1} + \beta x_n
     &= 0
\end{align*}$

We need two starting values, pick $x_0 = 1$ for convenience giving $x_1 = y_0$, and you are set.

Another road is to recognize the recurrence as a Möbius tranformation:

$\begin{align*}
   w_{n + 1}
     &= \frac{a w_n + b}{c w_n + d}
\end{align*}$

It turns out those compose just like $2 \times 2$ matrices multiply, so if you define:

$\begin{align*}
  M
    &= \pmatrix{a & b \\
                c & d} \\
  M^n
    &= \pmatrix{a^{(n)} & b^{(n]} \\
                c^{(n)} & d^{(n)}}
\end{align*}$

then:

$\begin{align*}
   w_n
     &= \frac{a^{(n)} w_0 + b^{(n)}}{d^{(n)} w_0 + d^{(n)}}
\end{align*}$

Yet another way is given by Mitchell "An Analytic Ricatti Solution for Two-Target Discrete-Time Control", Journal of Economic Dynamics and Control 24:4 (2000), pp 615-622.

Define the auxilliary sequence:

$\begin{align*}
  x_n
    &= \frac{1}{1 + \eta w_n}
\end{align*}$

to get:

$\begin{align*}
  x_{n + 1}
    &= \frac{(d \eta - c) x_n + c}
             {b \eta^2 - (a - d) \eta - c) x_n + a \eta + c}
\end{align*}$

Picking $\eta$ so that $b \eta^2 - (a - d) \eta - c = 0$, this is a linear recurrence. Bonus is that it is first order, so it can be solved even if the coefficients aren't constant.